# Why was my off-topic flag disputed on a math question?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, disputed-flags

I recently ran into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400432/the-change-making-algorithm-proof

The question is clearly not a programming question, but proof questions may not be totally on-topic for Math.SX.  How should proof request questions be handled?  Should they be migrated?  Flagged?  My off-topic flag was disputed, and I want to learn how to better handle this kind of situation.

Comment: What did you actually cast a flag for?

Comment: @Servy Off-topic, not a programming question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The users in triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8167324) marked the question as Should Be Improved, rather than Unsalvageable, which they shouldn't have (it's not salvageable, there's no possible way for us to fix this question as it's just entirely off topic) and that disputed your flag (which it also shouldn't happen, as marking as post as Should Be Improved doesn't mean it doesn't merit closure).  The later is being revisited by SE, and will hopefully be changed eventually.  The former is something we'll probably have to live with, as getting people to actually mark unsalvageable content as unsalvageable is *super* hard.

I've cast a close vote, so now it's at least in the CV queue.  You didn't actually do anything wrong here.  You did exactly the right thing in response to this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer.  The Triage is a great addition and will only improve over time.  I appreciate you taking the time to look into this.

Comment: @Servy: How did you get the review that fast?

Comment: @Deduplicator The History tab of the queue and Ctrl+F for the question title.  The question was asked (and the flag cast) half an hour ago, so it was only on the second page.  Had this been asking about an old question with a flag that was cast, say, even a few days ago, finding it in the history would be much harder; a mod would've probably needed to find it as they have better tools for such things.