# Criteria for flagging an off topic question

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403294/i-need-a-script-that-deletes-rows-after-a-certain-time-period) question as off topic

[image]

and found after some time that it was disputed. 
[image]

How can this not be an off topic question? This user did not take any effort and asking for a resource. How should I flag a question for off-topic?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8168973) is your triage review.  This question is also really Too Broad I'd say, rather than off topic.  Other than than that, the rest is all identical to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295037/1159478).  Bad reviewers are bad.

Comment: It's certainly off-topic as being _too broad_ or missing a minimal reproducible code sample. Fully agree your decision to flag it.

Comment: @Servy: thank you so much!

Comment: 3 should be improved for that question?! /facepalm

Comment: 2 of them from 600 reputation users. I didn't realize they had access to the review queue.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes first post, triage from 500+, thats how i got the access

Comment: I'm pinging them so they can come here and learn.  Learn why they should hang their heads in shame :|

Comment: I apologize for choosing should be improved instead of unsalvageable. I was speed reading through that review since I was in a hurry to get back to work and I am usually on the nicer side of my choices of giving users a chance to edit their post before flagging it. Next time I will be sure to be more strict. I see this as a learning experience so thanks for showing me this :).

Comment: @TravisJ  [disputed](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8193469) ,[another flagged question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440896/try-hard-to-play-vemio-video-on-cms-page-but-failed).... What should I do, these are definately increasing my disputed flag count... there are many of these

Comment: @TravisJ here [review by ~4k user](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8206508)

Comment: @Will : Is there a way I can ensure these questions get closed?

Comment: Grab hold of your monitor, reach through the internet to the full extent of your arm, grab the offending reviewers by their necks, and wring them until they vote to close.